# How to break out of nested loop after it iterates a given number of times?

Tags: python

I have been trying to get this to work for a while. I was trying to make an exponentiation program that uses nested loops. But I can't seem to break out of the loop after it goes to the power of x. I know it might be obvious to the experts but I can't seem to get this. My major struggle are with loops. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

```
number=int(input("enter number"))
power_of=int(input("enter number"))
for i in range(power_of):
    multiple=1
    while number>0:
        multiple=multiple*number

print(multiple)
```

Comment: In this, each time you run the loop in for, you reset multiple to 1, so not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `number` never changes, so the while loop is either a no-op (if `number` is zero or negative), or an infinite loop (if it is positive).

Comment: Your code appears to be wrong. Besides, have you tried to check the time inside the loop every now and then and raise an exception (or break) if some limit is reached?

Comment: The simplest way to break out of a loop after a certain amount of time, you have to keep track of the amount of time you've spent, and check each time through the loop. (The only tricky bit, at least pre-3.3, is deciding which time function you want to use, which depends on how exact you want the check to be, and which platform(s) you care about.)

Comment: I want to flag this but I can't put my finger on why exactly it needs to be deleted... so I'm just downvoting it for being very low quality.

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop will never complete if `number` is greater than 0. The inner loop is not needed, instead you should multiply `number` in the `for` loop.

```
number = int(input("enter number"))
power_of = int(input("enter number"))
multiple = 1
for i in range(power_of):
  multiple = multiple*number

 print(multiple)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number = int(input("enter number"))
power_of = int(input("enter number"))
for i in range(power_of):
    multiple=1
    while number > 0:
        multiple=multiple*number
```

1) you have an infinite loop that will never exit

2) you shouldn't use nested loops for exponentiation because you only need one..
the only way you can do exponentiation (its formal definition) is if the inside loop were to simulate multiplication with a series of additions....

to do it properly as a single loop it would look like

```
number = int(input("enter number"))
power_of = int(input("enter number"))
result = 0
for i in range(power_of):
    result += number * number
print(result)
```

to do this as a nested loop replace 'number * number' with a loop that will add number to itself number times, replacing the multiplication with looped addition...

Answer (score -1):

```
import datetime

time_start = datetime.datetime.now()
while (1): # some sort of loop
    if datetime.datetime.now() >= (time_start + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 1)):
         print('stopped')
         break
    print('looping')
```

Comment: While OP's question title is unclear, I'm fairly certain there is no time component to his problem.

Comment: It is an attempt at an answer, so it shouldn't be deleted on the basis of not being an answer. But perhaps the question should be closed or edited if it isn't clear what's being asked.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear in my wording. But my question doesn't involve the datetime module. I was trying trying to get my program to work. I was trying to do an exponentiation program. I guess I was over thinking it.But thanks for the help anyways.